# React Final Form Error: Must specify either a render prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-final-form, fluent-ui

I am trying to build a simple form with **React-Final-Form** like this:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import {
  PrimaryButton,
} from "office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Button";
import { Form , Field } from "react-final-form";
import { FORM_ERROR } from "final-form";
import { IUserFormValues } from "../../models/user";
import { RootStoreContext } from "../../stores/rootStore";
import TextInputNew from "./TextInputNew";

const NewUIForm = () => {
  const rootStore = React.useContext(RootStoreContext);
  const { login } = rootStore.userStore;
  return (
    <Form
      onSubmit={(values: IUserFormValues) =>
        login(values).catch((error) => ({
          [FORM_ERROR]: error,
        }))
      }

      render={({
        handleSubmit,

      }) => (
        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <Field name="email" component={TextInputNew} />
          <Field name="email" component={TextInputNew} />
          <PrimaryButton type='submit' text="Save" />
        </Form>
      )}
    />
  );
};
export default NewUIForm;
```

The `TextInputNew` Component is this:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { TextField } from "office-ui-fabric-react/lib/TextField";
import { FieldRenderProps } from "react-final-form";

interface IProps extends FieldRenderProps<string, HTMLInputElement> {}

const TextInputNew: React.FC<IProps> = ({ input }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <input {...input} />
      <TextField label="Standard" />
    </div>
  );
};
export default TextInputNew;
```

Then I got this error when I use this `NewUIForm` component

> Error: Must specify either a render prop, a render function as children, or a component prop to ReactFinalForm

By the way, the UI framework is **Fluent-UI**
Can anyone help me? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're second `<Form>` should be `<form>`.

```
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <Field name="email" component={TextInputNew} />
      <Field name="email" component={TextInputNew} />
      <PrimaryButton type='submit' text="Save" />
    </form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but after that, I'll have 2 input fields for each field, I think one comes from the <input> and another comes from the <Textfield>, do you know how to solve this?

Comment: You have to pass the `{...input}` into the `TextField` and remove the `<input>`.

Answer (score 1):

To anyone else who might encounter this vague error message, the issue is something going wrong in the render function of <Form>.

For OP, it was using the wrong form tag inside of <Form>.
For me, it was a misspelled property on a <Field> component `(components={MyComponent}`, oops).

Since the error can be caused by any number of reasons and the message wasn't very specific, one can get an idea of where the problem might be via browser debugger, in my case this is what it looked like:

[image: browser stack trace]